# Trigger JS codes when remove product from cart

Tags: magento2, cart

I want to add a tracking code when the user remove the product from the cart. I searched on a few questions here but to no avail. Of course I can use jQuery to monitor the **Remove** button on mini-cart and sidebar, but I don't think it is the best practice. Here is my codes so far:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function($){
    "use strict";
    $("form.form-cart a.action-delete, .minicart-items-wrapper a.delete").click(function(){
        //My tracking codes
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Magento has already implemented this part. We should re-use it.

Take a look at: `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js`

```
$(document).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, xhr, settings) {
   ......
});

/**
 * Events listener
 */
$(document).on('submit', function (event) {
    ......
});
```

As we can see, there are two event listeners: `ajaxComplete` and `submit`. We can follow the same logic.

app/code/Vendor/Tracking/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="vendor.tracking.data"
                   class="Vendor\Tracking\Block\Tracking"
                   template="Vendor_Tracking::tracking/js.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Vendor/Tracking/Block/Tracking.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Tracking\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Tracking extends Template
{

}
```

app/code/Vendor/Tracking/view/frontend/templates/tracking/js.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Vendor\Tracking\Block\Tracking */
?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
  "*": {
    "Vendor_Tracking/js/tracking": {}
  }
}
</script>
```

app/code/Vendor/Tracking/view/frontend/web/js/tracking.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/section-config'
], function ($, sectionConfig) {
    'use strict';
    /**
     * Events listener
     */
    $(document).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, xhr, settings) {
        var sections;

        if (settings.type.match(/post|put|delete/i)) {
            sections = sectionConfig.getAffectedSections(settings.url);
            if (sections) {
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Events listener
     */
    $(document).on('submit', function (event) {
        var sections;

        if (event.target.method.match(/post|put|delete/i)) {
            sections = sectionConfig.getAffectedSections(event.target.action);
            if (sections) {
            }
        }
    });
});
```

We can re-use `Magento_Customer/js/section-config` or create your own script if you want. But we need to know that the section config has section URLs.

```
{
  "*": {
    "Magento_Customer/js/section-config": {
      "sections": {
        ......
        "customer/account/logout": [
          "recently_viewed_product",
          "recently_compared_product"
        ],
        "customer/account/loginpost": "*",
        "customer/account/createpost": "*",
        "customer/account/editpost": "*",
        "customer/ajax/login": [
          "checkout-data",
          "cart"
        ],
        "catalog/product_compare/add": [
          "compare-products"
        ],
        "catalog/product_compare/remove": [
          "compare-products"
        ],
        "catalog/product_compare/clear": [
          "compare-products"
        ],
        "sales/guest/reorder": [
          "cart"
        ],
        "sales/order/reorder": [
          "cart"
        ],
        "checkout/cart/add": [
          "cart"
        ],
        "checkout/cart/delete": [
          "cart"
        ],
        "checkout/cart/updatepost": [
          "cart"
        ],
        "checkout/cart/updateitemoptions": [
          "cart"
        ]
        .....
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, however when you try to actually get that section data, for example, customerData.get('cart'), it will always be empty which makes this whole scheme pretty useless for tracking purposes