# Magento 2: Change "Add to Cart" Button text When item is removed from the minicart

Tags: magento2, addtocart, mini-cart

I rename the "addtocart" button text to "item in cart" when product is in cart. but if i remove item from minicart at that time i want to again set button text as "addtocart".

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/200034/51548

Comment: Please check answer I've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change button text by create **mixin**

Create **requirejs-config.js** file :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
   config: {
       mixins: {
           'Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/sidebar-mixin': true
            }
        },
     }
};
```

Create sidebar-mixin.js file :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar-mixin.js

and override below function in your mixin with custom code to change add to cart button title

```
/**
* Update content after item remove
*
* @param {Object} elem
* @private
*/
_removeItemAfter: function (elem) {
    var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

    if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
        $(document).trigger('ajax:removeFromCart', {
            productIds: [productData['product_id']],
            productInfo: [
                {
                    'id': productData['product_id']
                }
            ]
        });

        let addToCartButton = $("#product-addtocart-button");
        addToCartButton.find('span').text('Your Custom Title');
        addToCartButton.attr('title', 'Your Custom Title');

        if (window.location.href.indexOf(this.shoppingCartUrl) === 0) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey !! I appreacite your efforts, but its not working :(

Comment: I've just added the function needs to be rewrite, the code provided above is not a mixin file's code.

Comment: Try with replacing this function in default sidebar.js.

Comment: Also you can override sidebar.js in your custom theme and then replace above function.

Comment: @Fenashah is it worked for you?

Comment: yes but it reloads the page.

Comment: i want to update the button text without refreshing the page. any solution for that?

Comment: I am not sure why your page is getting refreshed. As I checked on my local instance it does not refreshes the page.

Comment: @Fenashah Check this video https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/4164311?key=17e314b4c5c31d552a3da02ea3b84149

Comment: yes it worked amazingly. Sorry i sidebar js was already present in third party module that is why it didnt worked for me. But now its working perfect. :)

Comment: Thank You for Helping. :)

Comment: @Fenashah you're welcome. Can you please accept it as solution. Thanks!